# Macro Take String with comma?

Tags: c++, string, macros

So if I have a macro like this (simplified example)

```
#define LOG(TYPE) LOG_STUFF(TYPE, #TYPE);
```

I want to use it like this

```
LOG(TMap<int32, int32>);
```

So #TYPE should become `"TMap<int32, int32>"` but instead it becomes `"TMap<int32"` and comma is taken as next parameter. Can I fix this or do I have to pass string manually?

Comment: You mean comma, not colon

Comment: `#define LOG(...) LOG_STUFF(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__);`

Comment: Macros are generally discouraged in modern C++. They have many drawbacks compared to functions, and you have discovered one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to do some testing and log stuff. definitely not production code. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Add extra `()`, like this `LOG((TMap<int32, int32>));`

Comment: @john nice trick! It works for the string part, it doesn't for other part that wasn't included in my question :) in my case `sizeof(TYPE)`